# Angular 2 : reactively reflect change in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a simple Angular 2 application with left side menu and a main content area on the right.

In my main content area i have a profile component when a can change the users profile image, my problem is that i have this image displayed in my left side menu, so when i change to profile image i would like to reflect this change in my side menu component.

Any suggestion ?

**CODE EXEMPLE :**

**sidemenu.component.html**

```
<img [src]="profileImg"/>
```

I would like to update the ***profileImg*** property as soon as i upload a new profile image in profileComponent without refreshing.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Try ViewChild. See more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html).